# How to Implement a Javascript Plugin

Tags: javascript

I'd like to implement a Javascript plugin available at internet (http://jpanelmenu.com/) but, due to the fact of being a new student of Javascript, I do not know how to write the necessary code in the HTML file, for this reason it does not work. please, could somebody help me with this deal?

Comment: Maybe start with jQuery's tutorial on making a plugin... http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Comment: You got the whole description on how to get it going, what do you want help with exactly?

Comment: Ummm... what are you asking us?  Are you just giving us a plugin and its instructions or is there an actual question here?

Comment: I think the key piece of info here is " I do not know how to write the necessary code in the HTML file"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the missing chunk of code example:

```
 <a href="#menu" class="menu-trigger ss-icon">&#xED50;</a>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#usage">Usage</a></li>
            <li><a href="#inner-workings">Inner-Workings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#animation">Animation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#options">Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="#api">API</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tips">Tips &amp; Examples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#license">License</a></li>
            <li><a href="#changelog">Changelog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Edited to add the relevant script bit

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();
        jPM.on();
    });
</script>
```

And be sure you are including jQuery on your page

Comment: thanks for your help, Ted. I tested your code and I almost got it. what about the following codes?

var jPM = $.jPanelMenu();

and

var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
    menu: '#custom-menu-selector',
    trigger: '.custom-menu-trigger-selector'
});

and

jPM.on();

where do they go?
once more, thanks.

Comment: Ted, I thank you a lot for your help. It worked!!!